# Dynamically generate form input fileds increment and decrement on click of button using pure javascript only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**ES6 /Pure javascript**/ **No Framework or jquery**/ **Document.createElement() / Node.appendChild()**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEUJD.jpg)

Making an HTML form where users have to add Members details.trying to make a button that generates a new set op input fields with increasements in the className/id or placeholder, like: The first generated input should have a className/id or placeholder of input1 and the next with a className/id or placeholder of input2 and so on.

I have create a script but it dynamically add input field but does not increment the count on adding member .increment must start form 1 to 10 only.

On Click of add button the input field must add and the count must increment on every click of add member with limit of max 10 members only .

And on click of delete button the input field must delete the member
input field decrement the count.

```
 <div class="container ">
    <form action="">
        <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="abc@test.com">
         <input class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" value="8888888888">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button addMember">
                    Add Member
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button delMember">
                    Delete Member
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button resetForm">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<section class="addinputs">
</section>
</div>


 <script>
    document.querySelector(".addMember").addEventListener('click', getAdd);
function getAdd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
         var count=1;
          document.querySelector('.addinputs').innerHTML+=` 
          <div class="addedMember">
          <input class="name ${count}"  type="text" placeholder="Name ${count}">
            <input class="email ${count}"  type="email" placeholder="Email ${count}">
             <input class="phone ${count}"  type="text" placeholder="Phone ${count}">
          </div>    
            `;
count++;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed logic errors

Is this what you're looking for?

```
document.querySelector(".addMember").addEventListener('click', getAdd);
document.querySelector(".delMember").addEventListener('click', getDel);

//Count as a global variable, not local
var count=0;

function getAdd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Set a limit on count
    if(count <= 10) {
        document.querySelector('.addinputs').innerHTML+=` 
          <div class="addedMember">
          <input class="name ${count}"  type="text" placeholder="Name ${count}">
            <input class="email ${count}"  type="email" placeholder="Email ${count}">
             <input class="phone ${count}"  type="text" placeholder="Phone ${count}">
          </div>    
        `;
         count++;
    }
}

function getDel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Dont let count go below 0
    if(count > 0) {
        //Retrieve array of all added members
        var added = document.getElementsByClassName("addedMember");

        //Retrieve the last of all added members
        var lastadded = added[added.length - 1];

        //Remove the last added member from the DOM
        lastadded.parentNode.removeChild(lastadded);
        count--;
    }

}
```

Comment: getAdd function not working with if statement and getDel function is also not working it give error undefine lastadded

Comment: My apologies, the if statement i made a last second adjustment to and had used the wrong operator. I have edited to fix this. As for the getDel function, did you change the way your HTML works? Given the example you gave, it works perfectly.